# InDesign: vertical align text with linked inline image

Tags: adobe-indesign, alignment, formatting

I need to vertically align the *Google Cloud Vision* paragraph with the symbol next to it, which is a vector placed within the text frame.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Left click the vector icon
- Choose Anchored Object > Options
- Play around with the 'Y Offset' value until this looks as you want it

Answer (score 2):

You can either baseline shift the symbol DOWN or baseline shift the text next to it UP. If you've got a lot of them then save it as a paragraph style.

Answer (score 0):

Combining the above two answers, you can choose a Y offset and create an Object Style via Windows/Styles/Object Styles. This way you can replicate the embedded object with the preferred text height several times.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the inline item as if it were text, and adjust the **baseline shift** in the **Character Panel**.

[image]

You can then copy the text, as text, and paste it and the inline graphic will remain consistent.